# How to install Brackets on Fedora 38?

Tags: json, linux, installation, fedora

Fedora 38. I'm trying to install an application is text editor. I got the following file from its website: https://github.com/brackets-cont/brackets/releases/tag/v2.2.1
brackets-2.2.1.tar.gz. But I don't know how to make and installation of these, or what I need to know. If you check the README.md is says nothing. Only I see there's some javascript and JSON files.

I've decompressed and give me a folder in which are the following files:

[image]

Comment: Looks like use npm